# Redeclared as different kind of symbol in c program

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a program for school. I need to create a chart of temperature conversions given by the user of between 1 to 100. I keep getting the error "redeclared as different kind of symbol" and I'm not sure how to fix it. I also included a picture of the compiler with the errors. [compiler image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tXOV.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int toFahrenheit(int celOne, int fahOne);

int toCelsius(int celTwo, int fahTwo); 


int main(void) {    //main


    int tempNum;   //intialize user given temperature
    int tempNumnegative = -tempNum; //initialize negative temperature num


    //ask user for number between 1 and 100
    printf ( "\nPlease enter an odd number between 1 to 100:" );
    scanf ("%d", &tempNum);

    //If Else statement to make sure it is a number between 1 to 100 and reject other numbers

    if ( (tempNum > 100) || (tempNum < 1) ) {
        puts ( "\nError; Number must be a number between 1 to 100." );
        }

    else { 

    printf("\n____________________________");
    printf(" C\tF\t|\t|\tF\tC");
    printf("\n____________________________");

    //For loop to print 
    for ( tempNumnegative >= tempNum; tempNumnegative++ ) {
        printf("\n%d\t%d\t|\t|\t%d\t%d\n", toFahrenheit(int celOne, int fahOne) , toCelsius(int celTwo, int fahTwo));
    } 
    }
}

int toFahrenheit(int celOne, int fahOne) //function
{  

    int celOne= tempNum; //celcuis one equals the given value
    int fahOne = (9 / 5) * celOne + 32; //equation for f to c
}

int toCelsius(int celTwo, int fahTwo) //function
{

    int fahTwo = tempNum; 
    int celTwo = (5 / 9) * (fahTwo - 32); //equation for c to f 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message.  It probably includes a line number where your code is failing

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this comment. I provided an image with the compiler for you in the original post.

Comment: Much preferred to copy and paste your error messages.  I see you have fixed a lot, but your error messages pointed out these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four important problems in your code

1. You redeclare function parameters as local variables.

   ```
   int toFahrenheit(int celOne, int fahOne) //function
   {  
       // Remove the type since `celOne' is already declared
       // as a function parameter.        
       celOne = tempNum; // celcuis one equals the given value
       fahOne = (9 / 5) * celOne + 32;
       return (9 / 5) * celOne + 32; // equation for f to c
   }
   ```
2. You don't return from the functions supposed to return `int`.
3. Your calculations in `toCelsuis()` should give `0` because of integer divition, change `5 / 9` to `5.0 / 9.0`. And wrong values in `toFahrenheit()` for the same reason.
4. The `tempNum` variable is only declared in `main()` so it's not declared in any of the conversion functions, and also it's completely unclear what you intend with `tempNum`.

Comment: I fixed the first 3 issues, thanks. the tempNum is suppose to be a user given number between 1 to 100 that I provide a chart with the conversion of both Celsius and Fahrenheit to. Do I just redeclare it in the new functions of toCelsius and toFahrenheit or how to I go about using that user given number in those functions. The book I'm using isn't very clear with it's examples.

Comment: It depends, do you want to store the value in it? If so, assign to it the return value!

Comment: I got it all fixed now. Thanks for your help.